# Geom_smooth not appearing in simple plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(R3L12, aes(x=Time, y=HeartRate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

This is the output of dput(head(R3L12, 20))

```
structure(list(Date = c("2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", 
"2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", 
"2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", 
"2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-23", 
"2015-05-23", "2015-05-23"), Time = c("07:25:00", "07:40:00", 
"07:45:00", "09:10:00", "11:45:00", "11:55:00", "12:05:00", "12:35:00", 
"12:45:00", "13:30:00", "13:40:00", "13:45:00", "13:55:00", "14:00:00", 
"14:05:00", "14:10:00", "14:20:00", "14:25:00", "14:30:00", "14:35:00"
), Turtle = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("R3L1", "R3L11", 
"R3L12", "R3L2", "R3L4", "R3L8", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1", "R8L4", 
"R8NAT123"), class = "factor"), HeartRate = c(7.56457, 6.66759, 
17.51107, 9.72277, 19.44553, 13.07674, 28.115, 14.99467, 17.16947, 
40.40479, 37.76642, 29.98933, 43.5329, 49.61471, 47.74245, 44.10196, 
21.35316, 44.68609, 49.25255, 29.98933)), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code of a plot I tried to create. I'm confused because when I plot it, the geom_smooth doesn't show up. `Time` is a factor variable, and `HeartRate` is a double. I'm new to R so let me know if you need more information!

[image]

Comment: Your `Time` value is not in a numerical format. Maybe you should check its format and convert it either as a numerical or a date format. If this is not working, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset.

Comment: @dc37 I'm not exactly sure how I would do that since my data set is very big.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(R3L12, 20))`. If your data set is very big, like you say, this will select only the first 20 rows.

Comment: `ggplot(R3L12, aes(x=as.numeric(Time), y=HeartRate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different solution in two ways. (1) It redefines aes inside geom smooth. (2) It treats the time character values as ordinal, and thus it treats different measurements as equidistant. Depending on your hypotheses, this is not always the best thing to do. But sometimes it may be exactly what you want.

```
R3L12<-structure(list(Date=c("2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23","2015-05-23"),
                      Time=c("07:25:00","07:40:00","07:45:00","09:10:00","11:45:00","11:55:00","12:05:00","12:35:00","12:45:00","13:30:00","13:40:00","13:45:00","13:55:00","14:00:00","14:05:00","14:10:00","14:20:00","14:25:00","14:30:00","14:35:00"),
                      Turtle=structure(c(3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L),
                                         .Label = c("R3L1","R3L11","R3L12","R3L2","R3L4","R3L8","R3L9","R4L8","R8L1","R8L4","R8NAT123"),class="factor"),
                      HeartRate=c(7.56457,6.66759,17.51107,9.72277,19.44553,13.07674,28.115,14.99467,17.16947,40.40479,37.76642,29.98933,43.5329,49.61471,47.74245,44.10196,21.35316,44.68609,49.25255,29.98933)),row.names=c(NA,20L),class="data.frame")

ggplot(R3L12,aes(x=Time,y=HeartRate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=as.numeric(factor(Time)),y=HeartRate))
```

[image]

Comment: This changes the time values into NA. Time is in the format H:M:S

Comment: This answer worked the best and was very simple to understand and replicate! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If times are unevenly spaced, as this is the case, and you want distance between x-axis points to reflect the actual time that is elapsed, you must convert your time variable into a POSIXct object. This may also change the way the smoothing line is shown, because the density of the points will change over the x-axis.

```
R3L12$time.posix <- as.POSIXlt(paste(R3L12$Date, R3L12$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ggplot(R3L12, aes(x=time.posix, y=HeartRate)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `lubridate` package:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= DateTime, y = HeartRate))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()+
  scale_x_datetime( breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image]